# How to prevent deactivated records to appear in the "recent" lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, model-driven, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm working on a model-driven PowerApps app and I've come across this issue: I would like to prevent users from adding relationships to deactivated records. I have a many to many relationship in my example.

Here the deactivated record shows up in the "recent" view.

[image: Deactivated record showing in lookup]

Is there a way to either hide deactivated in the recent view or can I force the default view to be only active ones?

EDIT: Or is there a way to style the deactivated with a strike-through or something?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we don't have lot of configuration/customization control around this setting. It's like "all or none" kinda setting, where we can use the "most recently used" aka MRU items as is or you can turn off, so users has to choose the records from views - in which we can apply filters to show only "Active" records.

[image]

You can submit an idea on MS PowerApps site, so community can vote for it and MS can give us more options.

Comment: Whereabout do you find this setting? Since it is a M-M relation I either have a subgrid or show the relation using the "Related" tab but I can't seem to find the setting for either.

Comment: I did find it on a "lookup" field but I can't use that for M-M unfortunately.